# Too many query rows 50001

Tags: apex, class

Can anyone please tell me if there is something wrong with the scrip below. I am using LIMIT 50000 but still getting this error. I will appreciate any help!

code:

```
    //for mws chart
  AggregateResult[] groupedSales 
  =[SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c), SUM(Detail_Total__c)
   FROM MWSOrderItem__c 
   WHERE  Purchase_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:365 AND Buyer_lookup__c =:UserInfo.getUserId()
   GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c)
   ORDER BY CALENDAR_YEAR(Purchase_Date__c),CALENDAR_MONTH(Purchase_Date__c) ASC LIMIT 50000 ];

  List1 = new List<String>();  

 for (AggregateResult ar11 : groupedSales )  {

   List1.add(String.valueof(ar11.get('expr0')+'/'+String.valueof(ar11.get('expr1'))));
   List1.add(String.valueof(ar11.get('expr2')));

 }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Limit in your query does not apply on the Total number of rows which were accessed but on the number of AggregatedRows returned. Thus if 1 of your Aggregated Rows has touched more than 1 rows you hit the limit...

This is implied in the documentation: [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm)

> Queries that include aggregate functions are subject to the same
>   governor limits as other SOQL queries for the total number of records
>   returned. **This limit includes any records included in the aggregation**,
>   not just the number of rows returned by the query. If you encounter
>   this limit, you should add a condition to the WHERE clause to reduce
>   the amount of records processed by the query.

but it's not 100% clear ;-)

Comment: I have a question, if we are making an update to this object and this query is running at the same time,  will it probably hit the governor limits?

Comment: at the same time means in the same context, sequential or in parallel ?

Comment: let me explain, this code is for a dashboard that I created for the users. We are making a mass update in this object. so it is in parallel.

Comment: so if the syntax of the code is good, this mass updating process must be affecting the query calls and hitting the governor limits

Comment: well, if you have more than 50000 records of MWSOrderItem__c with Purchase Date within the last year for the running user, it will hit the limits regardless of any updates you are making.

Comment: ManSpan, most of the users have more than 50000 records. is there any other way to get the data, or it is out of my hands programming talking.

Comment: is @Readonly an option ?? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_ReadOnly.htm

Comment: I haven't used readonly before, i am very new in salesforce so everyday i am finding new stuff or tricks. I will try this and I will let you know

Comment: ManSpan, that made the magic.. thank you so much. I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Also if you have two queries one with 40,000 records and another with 50,000 records. the total number of rows returned is 90,000